# convert function to delphi 2010 (unicode)

Tags: delphi, unicode, delphi-2010

How to convert this function to Delphi 2010 (Unicode)?

```
function TForm1.GetTarget(const LinkFileName:String):String;
var
   //Link : String;
   psl  : IShellLink;
   ppf  : IPersistFile;
   WidePath  : Array[0..260] of WideChar;
   Info      : Array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
   wfs       : TWin32FindData;
begin
  if UpperCase(ExtractFileExt(LinkFileName)) <> '.LNK' Then
  begin
    Result:='NOT a shortuct by extension!';
    Exit;
  end;

  CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IShellLink, psl);
  if psl.QueryInterface(IPersistFile, ppf) = 0 Then
  Begin
    MultiByteToWideChar(CP_ACP, MB_PRECOMPOSED, PAnsiChar(LinkFileName), -1, @WidePath, MAX_PATH);
    ppf.Load(WidePath, STGM_READ);
    psl.GetPath((@info), MAX_PATH, wfs, SLGP_UNCPRIORITY);
    Result := info;

  end
  else
    Result := '';
end;
```

Thanks

Comment: Say, what happens if I have a real file named "NOT a shortuct by extension!" and I make a link to it? How will this function's caller know the difference?

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, ppf.Load should be able to just take your LinkFileName directly with a cast to PChar (which is now PWideChar). Removing the MultiByteToWideChar line and using PChar(LinkFileName) instead of copying to a temporary variable should do it.

This would make the code look like this:

```
function TForm1.GetTarget(const LinkFileName:String):String;
var
   //Link : String;
   psl  : IShellLink;
   ppf  : IPersistFile;
   //WidePath  : Array[0..260] of WideChar;
   Info      : Array[0..MAX_PATH] of Char;
   wfs       : TWin32FindData;
begin
  if UpperCase(ExtractFileExt(LinkFileName)) <> '.LNK' Then
  begin
    Result:='NOT a shortuct by extension!';
    Exit;
  end;

  CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER, IShellLink, psl);
  if psl.QueryInterface(IPersistFile, ppf) = 0 Then
  Begin
    ppf.Load(PChar(LinkFileName), STGM_READ);
    psl.GetPath((@info), MAX_PATH, wfs, SLGP_UNCPRIORITY);
    Result := info;    
  end
  else
    Result := '';
end;
```

psl.GetPath is declared as using a LPTSTR in MSDN, so I believe you should get the Unicode version without changing that part.

Answer (score 1):

I have made some more changes to Michael's answer to use the proper string conversion to upper case, check for error conditions and remove unnecessary stuff:

```
function TForm1.GetTarget(const LinkFileName: String): String;
var
  psl: IShellLink;
  ppf: IPersistFile;
  wfs: TWin32FindData;
begin
  if Character.ToUpper(ExtractFileExt(LinkFileName)) <> '.LNK' Then
    Exit('NOT a shortcut by extension!');

  OleCheck(CoCreateInstance(CLSID_ShellLink, nil, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
    IShellLink, psl));
  if psl.QueryInterface(IPersistFile, ppf) = 0 Then
  Begin
    OleCheck(ppf.Load(PChar(LinkFileName), STGM_READ));
    SetLength(Result, MAX_PATH);
    OleCheck(psl.GetPath(PChar(Result), MAX_PATH, wfs, SLGP_UNCPRIORITY));
    Result := PChar(Result);
  end;
end;
```